# What Does Transcription Factor E25 Activate When a Cell is Transitioning from G1 to S

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology

Cyclin D/ CDK4 phosphorylates Rb allowing for the activation of transcription factor E25 during the G1 phase of the cell cycle. Supposedly, this transcription factor then activates as set of genes helping the cell to enter the S phase.

My question is what genes do E25 exactly activate? Are there any associated pathways with these genes involved in transitioning the cell from G1 to S?